# Add metadata to :attributes serializer (Active Model Serializers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

Is there a way I can add a non-model metadata attribute onto an `each_serializer`, without using the `:json_api` adapter?

```
render json: invoices, each_serializer: Invoices::ItemizedSerializer
```

I want it to be...

```
{
  data: [{..invoice 1...}, {...invoice 2...}]
  metadata: {total: 500}
}
```

instead of

```
[
  {..invoice 1...},
  {...invoice 2...}
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a custom adapter on a per controller basis:

```
render json: invoices, adapter: :json, each_serializer: Invoices::ItemizedSerializer, meta: {grand_total: grand_total}
```